# python decoding Non-English to use as url?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, io, decode

I have a variable such as `title`:

```
title = "révolution_essentielle"
```

I could encode and decode it like this for other purposes:

```
title1 = unicode(title, encoding = "utf-8")
```

But how do I preserve the Non-English and use it as part of a url string to access the url? For instance, I ideally want `https://mainurl.com/révolution_essentielle.html` by concatenating several strings including `title` like this:

```
url = main_url + "/" + title + ".html"
```

Could anyone kindly show me how to do that? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: @Zesima29, it shows up as "r\xc3\xa9volution" in the url

Comment: Are you looking for `urllib.parse.quote("révolution_essentielle")` (resp. `urllib.quote("révolution_essentielle")` for Py2)?

Comment: This isn't Spanish, it's French!

Comment: @OndrejK. Thanks but that returns a KeyError

Comment: @shenglih That very line I've pasted? Or something else? Py3:`import urllib.parse; urllib.parse.quote("révolution_essentielle")` -> `'r%C3%A9volution_essentielle'`; Py2: `import urllib ; urllib.quote("révolution_essentielle")` ->
`'r%C3%A9volution_essentielle'`

Comment: @OndrejK. Oh sorry I tested your line on another Non-English instance ``u'hey_there_who_likes_lego_that\xe3\u0192\xe2_\xe3_\xe2_\u0161\xe2_\xe3_\xe2_\u017e\xe2_s_all_that_needs_to_be_said_it\xe3\u0192\xe2_\xe3_\xe2_\u0161\xe2_\xe3_\xe2_\u017e\xe2_s_a_vector_with_a_million_uses_download_for_free_the_entire_alphabet_made_from_vector_lego'``... Sorry yours did work for the one I gave in the question

Comment: @shenglih OK, got two pieces of information: we're talking Python 2. And I really hope this produces valid URL material... encode your Unicode string first: `import urllib ; urllib.quote(u'hey_there_who_likes_lego_that\xe3\u0192\xe2_\xe3_...'.encode('utf8'))`

Comment: @OndrejK. That's perfect!! Thanks so much!

Comment: @lenz you are absolutely right! lol Thanks a lot! Quick question: the codes that work for any non-English language should be readily applicable to other non-English languages, correct?

Comment: Your problem really doesn't have anything to do with languages, it's just about encoding strings. The suggested method should work for any encoded string, I guess, no matter what language is used to produce the text in question.

Comment: @lenz true true, thanks lenz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize what we've talked about in the comments: there is a function for quoting URLs (replacing special characters with `%` prefix escape sequences.

For Python 2 (as used in this case), it's [`urllib.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote), which can be used as follows:

```
urllib.quote("révolution_essentielle")
```

When our input is an `unicode` object with wide characters, we need to also encode it first, e.g.:

```
urllib.quote(u'hey_there_who_likes_lego_that\xe3\u019\xe2_\xe3_...'.encode('utf8')).
```

Be ware though so that your representation matches the one expected/understood by the counterpart machine.

---

If we were talking Python 3, the equivalent function would be [`urllib.parse.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
urllib.parse.quote("révolution_essentielle")
```

Which can chew over `str` (unicode) parameters as well as encoded value in `bytes` object.